# Powershell - Excel add-in (XLAM) not loaded when file opened from script

Tags: excel, powershell, excel-addins, vba

I have an add-in file "add-in.xlam" enabled in Excel so that a set of custom add-in functions are available to all Excel files.  I made a new file 'Export VBA.xlsm' with a macro in Module1 called 'exportModule'.  When I open the new excel file manually and run exportModule, all works as expected.  I've created a PowerShell script to automate the process and if I step through the code, I noticed that the add-in.xlam is not loaded when 'Export VBA.xlsm' is opened.

Here's my PowerShell script:

```
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\FilePath\Export VBA.xlsm")
$excel.Visible = $true
$excel.Run("'Export VBA.xlsm'!Module1.exportModule")
$workbook.close()
$excel.quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
```

Here's my VBA macro:

```
Sub exportModule()

    Dim codeMod As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim vbProj As VBProject
    Dim vbComp As VBComponent
    Dim destDir As String
    Dim outputFileBase As String
    Dim vbProjectName As String
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim subIndex As Integer
    Dim outputFileName As String
    Dim moduleName As String

    vbProjectName = "add-in.xlam"
    destDir = "C:\Git\dev"
    outputFileBase = "add-in-|.txt"
    index = 1
    subIndex = 1

    For Each vbProj In Excel.AddIns.Application.VBE.VBProjects
        If InStr(1, Excel.AddIns.Application.VBE.VBProjects(index).FileName, vbProjectName) > 0 Then
            For Each vbComp In Excel.AddIns.Application.VBE.VBProjects(index).VBComponents
                If Excel.AddIns.Application.VBE.VBProjects(index).VBComponents(subIndex).Type = 1 Then
                    Set codeMod = Excel.AddIns.Application.VBE.VBProjects(index).VBComponents(subIndex)
                    moduleName = Excel.AddIns.Application.VBE.VBProjects(index).VBComponents(subIndex).Name
                    outputFileName = Replace(outputFileBase, "|", moduleName)
                    Call ExportVBComponent(codeMod, destDir, outputFileName)
                End If
                subIndex = subIndex + 1
            Next vbComp
        End If
        index = index + 1
    Next vbProj

End Sub
```

Any ideas?
Thanks,

Brian